# Aggregate daily data to give one warning output based on tiered warning system in multiple locations

Tags: r, string, date, aggregate

I am currently working with a large data set that records daily data at multiple locations and I would like to summarize the daily data to have one output giving the maximum warning level on that day (categories red/yellow/none).

Consider the following set up:

```
location = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D",4) , rep("E", 4))
date = rep(c("19991230", "19991231", "20000101", "20000102"), 5)
warning = c("Red", "None", "None", "None", "Yellow", "None", "Red", "None", "Yellow", "Yellow", "None", "Yellow", "None", "None", "None", "None", "Yellow", "None", "None", "None")

data = data.frame(location, date, warning)
```

I am trying to create a new column that will show "None" if no warnings occur on each specific day, "Yellow" if one or more yellow warning occurs (except if one or more "Red" warning occurs that same day) in which case the "Red" output takes priority.

I have considered using aggregate by date but I am unsure which function to apply.  I have also tried for loops over each date to try and !count "None" warnings to at least narrow it down but without any luck.  Perhaps I need to use ifelse and a for loop over the dates?  Poor attempts below:

```
aggregate(data, by=date, FUN)
```

or

```
data <- data %>%
group_by(date) %>%
mutate(day_warning_type = case_when(
warning != "None" ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE
)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Hopefully someone can at least help me in the right direction as I haven't made much progress so far as I am struggling to know how to work with character variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create counts on the warnings and create the flag based on the counts:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(day_warning_type = case_when(
    sum(warning == "Red") > 0 ~ "Red",
    sum(warning == "Red") == 0 & sum(warning == "Yellow") > 0 ~ "Yellow",
    TRUE ~ "None"
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 20 x 4
   location date     warning day_warning_type
   <fct>    <fct>    <fct>   <chr>           
 1 A        19991230 Red     Red             
 2 A        19991231 None    Yellow          
 3 A        20000101 None    Red             
 4 A        20000102 None    Yellow          
 5 B        19991230 Yellow  Red             
 6 B        19991231 None    Yellow          
 7 B        20000101 Red     Red             
 8 B        20000102 None    Yellow          
 9 C        19991230 Yellow  Red             
10 C        19991231 Yellow  Yellow          
11 C        20000101 None    Red             
12 C        20000102 Yellow  Yellow          
13 D        19991230 None    Red             
14 D        19991231 None    Yellow          
15 D        20000101 None    Red             
16 D        20000102 None    Yellow          
17 E        19991230 Yellow  Red             
18 E        19991231 None    Yellow          
19 E        20000101 None    Red             
20 E        20000102 None    Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with the `group_by`. It's maybe simpler to create a second dataset that summarizes by date, and then merge this back into the main dataset. See below

```
# Summarize each date based on number of Yellow/Red/None warnings
data_sum <- data %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(
    day_warning_none = length(which(warning == "None")),
    day_warning_yellow = length(which(warning == "Yellow")),
    day_warning_red = length(which(warning == "Red"))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Create a summary  measure
  mutate(
    day_warning = case_when(
      day_warning_red > 0 ~ "Red",
      day_warning_yellow > 0 ~ "Yellow",
      TRUE ~ "None"
    )
  )

head(data.sum)
  date     day_warning_none day_warning_yellow day_warning_red day_warning
  <fct>               <int>              <int>           <int> <chr>      
1 19991230                1                  3               1 Red        
2 19991231                4                  1               0 Yellow     
3 20000101                4                  0               1 Red        
4 20000102                4                  1               0 Yellow    

# Merge back in
data2 <- left_join(data, data_sum) %>%
  arrange(date)
head(data2, 10)

   location     date warning day_warning_none day_warning_yellow day_warning_red day_warning
1         A 19991230     Red                1                  3               1         Red
2         B 19991230  Yellow                1                  3               1         Red
3         C 19991230  Yellow                1                  3               1         Red
4         D 19991230    None                1                  3               1         Red
5         E 19991230  Yellow                1                  3               1         Red
6         A 19991231    None                4                  1               0      Yellow
7         B 19991231    None                4                  1               0      Yellow
8         C 19991231  Yellow                4                  1               0      Yellow
9         D 19991231    None                4                  1               0      Yellow
10        E 19991231    None                4                  1               0      Yellow
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I actually used this one as well as the shorter version above since it allowed me to inspect the number of warnings types per day.  Upvoted (will show when I have 2 more rep!).